# GWT SimplePager - Add History for every next and previous

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt

I need to implement a service like whenever a next or previous is clicked in pagination the browser should save the state so that while doing browser back it goes back to last accessed page.
Currently it is happening like when I enter any url in new tab page and in pagination if I click on next button, further I click browser back button it is going to new tab page.

Anybody please suggest how to achieve this.

I have tried following

```
    public class ShortenLastPagePager extends SimplePager implements ValueChangeHandler<String>
```

{

```
private int pageSize;


public ShortenLastPagePager( TextLocation location, Resources resources, boolean showFastForwardButton,
    int fastForwardRows, boolean showLastPageButton, int pageSize )
{
    super( location, resources, showFastForwardButton, fastForwardRows, showLastPageButton );
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}


@Override
public void setPageSize( int pageSize )
{
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}


@Override
public void setPageStart( int index )
{
    if ( getDisplay() != null ) {
        Range range = getDisplay().getVisibleRange();
        int myPageSize = 0;

        index = Math.min( index, getDisplay().getRowCount() );
        index = Math.max( 0, index );
        myPageSize = Math.min( pageSize, getDisplay().getRowCount() - index );

        if ( index != range.getStart() || myPageSize != range.getLength() ) {
            getDisplay().setVisibleRange( index, myPageSize );
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void nextPage()
{
    if ( getDisplay() != null ) {
        Range range = getDisplay().getVisibleRange();
        setPageStart( range.getStart() + range.getLength() );
    }
}


@Override
public void previousPage()
{
    if ( getDisplay() != null ) {
        Range range = getDisplay().getVisibleRange();
        setPageStart( range.getStart() - pageSize );
    }
}


@Override
public void lastPage()
{
    int remainder = getDisplay().getRowCount() % pageSize;
    if ( remainder > 0 ) {
        setPageStart( getDisplay().getRowCount() - remainder );
    } else {
        if ( getDisplay().getRowCount() / pageSize > 0 ) {
            setPageStart( getDisplay().getRowCount() - pageSize );
        } else {
            setPageStart( 0 );
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void firstPage()
{
    setPageStart( 0 );
}


@Override
public boolean hasPreviousPage()
{
    return getDisplay() == null ? false : getDisplay().getVisibleRange().getStart() > 0 && getDisplay().getRowCount() > 0;
}


@Override
public boolean hasNextPage()
{

    return getDisplay() == null ? false
        : getDisplay().getRowCount() > ( getDisplay().getVisibleRange().getStart() + pageSize );
}


@Override
public void onValueChange( ValueChangeEvent<String> event )
{
    event.getValue();
    System.out.println( event.getSource() );
}
```

}

It is not hitting onValueChange it is coming to nextPage

Comment: added in the description

Comment: How are you managing your app history? Are you using activities and places with history management? http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html or something else?

Comment: App History is getting manages with places getting mapped with PlaceHistoryMapper and it is getting binded. The main problem is to create history with Pagination as it doesn't have valuechanger rather it is working on nextPage, previousPage, lastpage, etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to add a value change listener to the pager you could put the code in the data provider (assuming you have one).

In the data provider that is providing the content (again I am assuming a table or list) then simply update the browser history as necessary.

Something like

```
@Override
protected void onRangeChanged(final HasData<YourObject> display) {

  // update browser URL without navigating
  History.newItem(historyMapper.getToken(place), false);

  ...
}
```

then add support into your place token for storing the paging data, start index, page length, that sort of thing.

You will need corresponding code at the start of your activity to read the paging data and handle it as necessary.

Ideally if you are using activities and places you want to avoid using the browser back button as generally it will cause a new place and new activity to be created which is a bit heavy. I would imagine you can code your way around this.

Comment: I have applied this change and it is working fine but this is making my application heavy. It will be good if you suggest something to handle at pager level, because I have a custom integer box also in application to enter a desired table page.

Comment: The problem is that the back/forward buttons will always interact with the places and activities. I guess you have some sort of `com.google.gwt.activity.shared.ActivityMapper` that maps Places to Activities. All I can think of is somehow caching the activity so that a place change does not recreate the activity but reuses and reconfigures the existing one.

Comment: Yes I am using ActivityMapper. I am also looking for the same. The problem here is SimplePager automatically use rangechangehandler to display data by setting index of startpage. It doesn't call place and activity, but here in my case it is calling place and activity that is what causing the application heavier.

Comment: If the user clicks a pager button then this should be okay - no place change there. Clicking one of these should trigger a range change which using the code above will update the URL but not trigger a place change. Only clicking the browser button should cause a place change. In this case you will have to handle the place change - possibly in the activity mapper and possibly by caching and reusing the activity so it is not so 'heavy'.

Comment: Yeah I am doing the same. This came to my mind later. hoping it works. Thanx a lot.

Comment: Hi pauli, I have done the changes like setting the dataprovider start as previous one. Now the problem is in this case table value is not changing. I have something like this in my pagination bar.
        display.addRangeChangeHandler( new RangeChangeEvent.Handler() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeChange( RangeChangeEvent event )
            {
                toPageList.setValue( ( event.getNewRange().getStart() / pageSize ) + 1 );
            }
        } );

Comment: I have never had to create a `RangeChangeHandler` directly - I have always used `AbstractDataProvider#addDataDisplay(HasData<T> display)` to bind the pager to the data provider. This in turn creates and adds a `RangeChangeHandler` and calls `onRangeChanged()` to handle the initial case.

Comment: I am also doing the same, but the problem here is it is not calling CachingActivityMapper and so mapper dont have a previous cached page.